# how to select something from the drop down already saved in a database using php?

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have this drop-down list of countries:

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="">Country...</option>
    <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <!-- Removed several options as they are not needed for question -->
    <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
    <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
    <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
```

When a user edits their profile, I want the country that the user selected (in the database) to be selected by default.

### Example

When the user registered, `Egypt` was selected. When the user edits their profile, I want this drop-down list to select `Egypt` by default (until changed).

Comment: I take for granted you will be using xhtml, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the `selected` attribute to the `option` the user chose when creating an account.

### Basic Idea

#### Foreach

```
<?php
$country_list = '<select name="country">';
$selected_country = $user_info['country'];
foreach($countries as $country){
 $is_selected = ($country===$selected_country);
 $country_list .= '<option value="'.$country.'"'.($is_selected ? ' selected' : '').'>$country</option>';
}
$country_list .= '</select>';
```

#### While

```
<?php
...
$country_list = '<select name="country">';
$selected_country = $user_info['country'];
$stmt->bind_result($country);
while($mysqli->fetch()){
 $is_selected = ($country===$selected_country);
 $country_list .= '<option value="'.$country.'"'.($is_selected ? ' selected' : '').'>$country</option>';
}
$country_list .= '</select>';
```

***Note:** While it will use up slightly more resources, I **would** suggest using an array of countries at the very least, but preferably store the countries in the database. The reason for the database being if you ever change the name of a country (e.g., USSR to Russia), you won't have to update it for each user as well (since they'd be linked to the `id` in the `countries` table). I'd suggest database or array due to the fact that sooner or later you'll probably change the markup of the `option` list at some point in time, and having the list in an array will make it possible to change a single line, rather than once for **every** country listed.*

Answer (score 0):

Html syntax is this:

```
<option value="AAAA" selected>label</option>
```

So in PHP, load from DB your values, and your selected value, when you print them in a loop, if current printing one is the selected one just echo a "selected".

Comment: is it not<option selected="selected"></option> ?

Comment: sorry you got it wrong i didn't mean i meant how to compare the value to what the database is returning

Comment: @dm03514, no, see [HTML Specification on the `selected` attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#attr-option-selected).

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable from the database value.
Store the entire `<select>` tag as a variable.
Find and replace the selected option value with the selected attribute.

```
$country_selected_value;
// defined from database
$country_select = '<select name="country">...</select>';
// ... represents your options
$value_search = 'value="'.country_selected_value.'"';
// what to look for in the select
echo str_replace($value_search , $value_search.'" selected="selected"', $country_select);
// displaying the select field with the selected option
```

If you need help getting data from the database there are many such topics already on SO.

Comment: so is it a better approach to store the country list in an array and then do a foreach loop right?

Comment: I would say no. A single find replace is much less intensive, or complicated.

Comment: @MohamedHassan, if you're referring to my approach, I wasn't sure how you were looping through the countries (`foreach` or `while`). However you're pulling the countries from the database (you *are* storing them in the database, right?), simply do the check when you're looping through them and generating the `option` list. Also, using iambriansread's approach, and use an `id` instead of the country `name`, then you will need to do a lookup for the `id` to do the `str_replace()`. It is common (and recommended) practice to do the checks within a loop, especially when you're pulling from a DB.

Comment: @MohamedHassan I was using the html which you already produced since you never said you had a PHP array of countries. The example you ask for is my answer.

Comment: @bfrohs The OP only mentions pulling the selected value from a database not all countries. He includes the select tag which he has already built. I would normally use the procedure you describe but I didn't think that would fit best with the OP's question and displayed example.

Comment: Why the down vote? It is valid and functional code and provides a solution to the OP's question.

Comment: @iambriansreed, you've got a point there. I still wouldn't suggest this route (and would recommend to put the countries into the database, since if the name is changed, it will be updated for the user too), but since the OP *did* present it as static HTML, I'll take the -1 back. You'll have to edit the answer first though (let me know when you do? Thanks!). I'd suggest specifying *why* you chose the answer you did in your answer.